# Is it possible to load dynamically a Phase Listener with JSF 1.2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, faces-config, phaselistener

I have been using a Phase Listener to debug my JSF application.

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to load it dynamically depending on, for example, a system property is set or not (so I can commit the thing, and not worry about having to remove it before deploy in production).
Does anyone know if there is a way to do that in `faces-config.xml`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add phaselisteners dynamically by [`UIViewRoot#addPhaseListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#addPhaseListener%28javax.faces.event.PhaseListener%29).

```
PhaseListener phaseListener = new YourPhaseListener();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().addPhaseListener(phaseListener);
```

You've only to do it on a per-view basis. It's perhaps better to keep the phase listener registered and let it take actions only when the desired system property is set or not.